# Rewind twice after unwinding twice

Tags: python, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I have a document in MongoDB and I'm trying to unwind it. I want to unwind a document with `comments` field then unwind the `replies` field inside each comment. I need to rewind it back afterwards.

So the document structure goes like this:

```
{
     "_id": <some_id>,
     "post_body": "test post",
     "author_id": <some_user_id>,
     "comments": [
          {
              "comment_body": "comment test",
              "comment_author_id": <some_user_id>,
              "replies": [
                   {
                       "reply_body": "reply test",
                       "reply_author_id": <some_user_id>
                   },
                   ... more items
              ]
          },
          ... more items
     ]
}
```

I am also trying to look up from a users table all the author data using the saved ids attached.

Here is my code right now:

```
            {
                "$match": {"post_id": post_id}
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "author_data"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": {
                    "path": "$comments",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "comments.comment_author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "comment_author_data"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": {
                    "path": "$comments.replies",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "comments.replies.reply_author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "reply_author_data"
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": '$_id',
                    "post_body": {"$first": "$post_body"},
                    "author": {"$first": "$authorData"},
                    "comments": {
                        "$push": {
                            "comment_body": "$comments.comment_body",
                            "comment_author_data": "$comment_author_data",
                            "replies": {
                                "$push": {
                                    "reply_body": "$comments.replies.reply_body",
                                    "reply_author_data": "$reply_author_data"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And I am getting this error

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Aggregation project operator not supported: '$push'

I want to get:

```
{
     "_id": <some_id>,
     "post_body": "test post",
     "author_data": {"author_name": "test1"},
     "comments": [
          {
              "comment_body": "comment test",
              "comment_author_data": {"author_name": "test1"},
              "replies": [
                   {
                       "reply_body": "reply test",
                       "reply_author_data": {"author_name": "test1"}
                   },
                   ... more items
              ]
          },
          ... more items
     ]
}
```

What do I need to change in my MongoDB query?

Comment: I took a look at your pipeline. The problem is occurring because of your second push. When I remove it, the pipeline error goes away.  However, when I do this, I'm ending up with a comment for each reply, which I don't think is what you want.  I recommend using the aggregation pipeline builder in either Compass or Atlas to build your pipeline.  This will allow you to visually see what is happening in each stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of scribbling with my code I have arrived at this code which gives me the result I needed.

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "post_id":"post_id"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"usersLookup",
         "localField":"author_id",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"author_data"
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":{
         "path":"$comments",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":True
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"usersLookup",
         "localField":"comments.comment_author_id",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"comment_author_data"
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":{
         "path":"$comments.replies",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":True
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"usersLookup",
         "localField":"comments.replies.reply_author_id",
         "foreignField":"_id",
         "as":"reply_author_data"
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "author":"$author_data",
            "post_body":"$post_body",
            "comment_body":"$comments.comment_body",
            "comment_author_data":"$comment_author_data"
         },
         "replies":{
            "$push":{
               "reply_body":"$comments.replies.reply_body",
               "reply_author_data":"$reply_author_data"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id._id",
         "post_body":{
            "$first":"$_id.post_body"
         },
         "author_data":{
            "$first":"$_id.author"
         },
         "comments":{
            "$push":{
               "comment_body":"$_id.comment_body",
               "comment_author_data":"$_id.comment_author_data",
               "replies":"$replies"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I had to use `$group` step twice to rewind the nested array back. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon a similar need in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Aggregation project operator not
>   supported: '$push'

This is because you have a nested `$push`. If you entered this aggregation pipeline in [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) shell, you should get an error message below:

```
  "errmsg": "Unrecognized expression '$push'",
```

This is because the nested operation is expected to be an [aggregation expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions), but `$push` is not an expression operator.

> What do I need to change in my MongoDB query?

To use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) after [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is actually a bit of anti-pattern. I'd recommend using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "author_data"
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "comments.comment_author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "comment_author_data"
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "usersLookup",
                    "localField": "comments.replies.reply_author_id",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "reply_author_data"
                }
            },
            {"$addFields": {
                "author_data": {
                    "$reduce": {
                        "input":"$author_data", 
                        "initialValue": "",
                        "in": "$$this"
                    }
                },
                "comments": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$comments",
                        "as": "c",
                        "in": {
                            "comment_author_id": "$$c.comment_author_id",
                            "comment_body": "$$c.comment_body",
                            "comment_author_data": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                    "$comment_author_data",
                                    { "$indexOfArray": [ "$comment_author_data._id", "$$c.comment_author_id" ] }
                                ]
                            },
                            "replies": {
                                "$map":{
                                    "input": "$$c.replies", 
                                    "as": "r", 
                                    "in":{
                                        "reply_body":"$$r.reply_body", 
                                        "reply_author_id":"$$r.reply_author_id", 
                                        "reply_author_data":{
                                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                                "$reply_author_data", 
                                                {"$indexOfArray": ["$reply_author_data._id", "$$r.reply_author_id"] }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 
            }}, 
            {"$project": {
                "author_data._id":0,
                "comment_author_data":0, 
                "comments.comment_author_data._id":0,
                "reply_author_data":0, 
                "comments.replies.reply_author_data._id":0
            }}
])
```

The above should resolve the nested array results from [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), without using `$unwind` and `$group`. The aggregation pipeline example above is written in MongoDB v4.2.

Comment: As this is a really good answer, this does not work on AWS DocumentDB. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html), `$map` and `$reduce` is still not supported.

Comment: @PaulRyanLucero, DocumentDB is not MongoDB. It only emulates the MongoDB API but runs on top of a different database backend. I'll remove the mongodb tag from the question. Please update your question to replace MongoDB with DocumentDB. In addition, using MongoDB official driver PyMongo, at some point you'll see unexpected behaviour as well.